# Regarding formik and yup

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, formik, yup

I have a componet where there is two button for submit on click one is for create post another is for draft; onSubmit I m calling post on click function and for draft I am doing
<Button

```
                        title="Add to Drafts"
                        type="button"
                        isLoading={isLoadingCreateDraft}
                        isDisabled={isLoadingCreateDraft}
                        onClick={() => {
                          isValid && addToDraft(values);
                        }}
```

Issue is when I click on addtoDraft buttom first then validation is not firing but after clicking on create post btn it works fine

```
 <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="justify-center items-center flex overflow-x-hidden backdrop-blur-md overflow-y-auto fixed inset-0 z-50 outline-none focus:outline-none">
              <div className="relative my-6 mx-auto w-[410px] -top-[5%]">
                {/*content*/}
                <div className="border-0 rounded-lg shadow-lg relative flex flex-col w-full bg-gray-900 outline-none focus:outline-none">
                  <div className="flex relative flex-col p-4">
                    <div className="my-4">
                      <h3 className="text-center text-base text-white mb-[30px]">
                        Create Your Post
                      </h3>
                      <Field
                        component="textarea"
                        name="content"
                        value={values.content}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        id="message"
                        className="block p-2.5 w-full h-[100px] text-sm text-gray-400 bg-transparent rounded-lg border border-gray-600 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                        placeholder="Write your thoughts here..."
                      />
                      {errors.content && touched.content ? (
                        <p className="bottom-[153px] error-msg">{errors.content}</p>
                      ) : null}
                      <button className="bottom-[153px] error-msg">
                        Remaining characters:
                        {values.content.length <= 10 ? 10 - values.content.length : 0}{" "}
                      </button>
                      {/* date picker added */}
                      <Field
                        name="scheduledAt"
                        min={currentDate}
                        value={values.scheduledAt}
                        // value={postdata.scheduledAt}
                        // onChange={(e: any) => {
                        //   handleChange;
                        //   // handleChange22(e);
                        // }}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        type="datetime-local"
                        className="px-2 w-full py-2 my-3 text-sm bg-transparent rounded-md border border-gray-500/40 text-gray-400"
                      />
                      {errors.scheduledAt && touched.scheduledAt ? (
                        <p className=" bottom-[78px] error-msg">{errors.scheduledAt}</p>
                      ) : null}
                      {/* <BsCalendar3Event className="text-[14px] absolute right-[15px] top-[12px]"></BsCalendar3Event> */}
                    </div>

                    <div className="flex justify-end items-end gap-8 my-3">
                      <Button
                        className={
                          isLoadingCreateDraft
                            ? "bg-blue-600 text-white text-base w-full px-3 py-1 rounded-sm cursor-not-allowed relative"
                            : "bg-blue-600 text-white text-base w-full px-3 py-1 rounded-sm"
                        }
                        title="Add to Drafts"
                        type="button"
                        isLoading={isLoadingCreateDraft}
                        isDisabled={isLoadingCreateDraft}
                        onClick={() => {
                          isValid && addToDraft(values);
                        }}
                      />

                      <Button
                        className={
                          isLoadingAddPost
                            ? "bg-blue-600 text-white text-base w-full px-3 py-1 rounded-sm cursor-not-allowed relative"
                            : "bg-blue-600 text-white text-base w-full px-3 py-1 rounded-sm"
                        }
                        title="Create Post"
                        type="button"
                        isLoading={isLoadingAddPost}
                        isDisabled={isLoadingAddPost}
                        // disabled={isSubmitting}
                        // onClick={createPost}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="absolute right-0">
                    <button className="btn-close" onClick={() => props.setShowPostModal(false)}>
                      <MdClose className="text-white text-[20px]"></MdClose>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Form>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: there is two button one for addtodraft another for create post and in both case validation for title date and time should be fired in my case validation is fired only one case

Comment: isValid is just the form property but you need to actually do the validation yourself or trigger the submit method otherwise isValid won't change.

Create a function that does schema.validate(values), and then any errors you catch and set to form data, see what I did here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73425133/transform-yup-validation-error-into-a-useable-object/73425134#73425134